# How do I dynamically append 2 Canvases to the document such that they overlap?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

My html includes two overlapping canvases.

```
<canvas id="imCanvas" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px;" width="512" height="512"></canvas>
<canvas id="mouseCanvas" style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px;" width="512" height="512"></canvas>
```

I want to append via javascript two new canvases to the document and fill them with the images from the first two. When I attempt this, I keep finding the fourth canvas is positioned to the right of the third one, even if I try to give them the same position. I've tried appending to a div or a paragraph with the same results.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleAppendData() {
    var appendDataP=document.getElementById("appendDataP");
    var c1=document.createElement('canvas');
    var c2=document.createElement('canvas');
    c1.style="z-index: 1";
    c2.style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; left:0px;";
    c1.width=512;
    c1.height=512;
    c2.width=512;
    c2.height=512;
    var canvas = document.getElementById('imCanvas');
    var mousecanvas = document.getElementById('mouseCanvas');
    var ctx1=c1.getContext('2d');
    var ctx2=c2.getContext('2d');
    ctx1.drawImage(canvas,0,0);
    ctx2.drawImage(mousecanvas,0,0)
    appendDataP.appendChild(c1);
    appendDataP.appendChild(c2);
}
</script>
```

Why is my second canvas appearing to the right of the first?

I've also tried `c2.style.position=c1.style.position` with the same result.

Comment: Wrap your 2 canvas elements in a div container. Set the container div as `position:relative` and the canvas elements as `position:absolute`.

Comment: Thanks @markE I tried this but it didn't work until I followed the updated answer and jsbin below. Clearly I have more to learn about absolute vs. relative positing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to position first canvas as absolute and second as relative, like that

```
c1.style.zIndex=1; c1.style.position="absolute";
c2.style.zIndex=2; c2.style.position="relative";
```

Comment: That seems to give the same result: c2 appears again to the right of c1. But I haven't grokked "absolute" vs. "relative" positioning, so I might look into that more. Thanks.

Comment: Problem with your code is how you work with "element.style".
Check this out http://jsbin.com/fovodagiru/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks--that works! I will have to read up more on adding styles and relative vs. absolute positioning.